# Change a string name from dotted to underscore and keep last dot

Tags: php

Hi i have a File name **`1208.flowers.blue.jpg`** I want to change this name into 
**`1208_flowers_blue.jpg`**

```
$str="1208.flowers.blue.jpg";
$count=substr_count($str,".");
if($count>1){
  //Change string to '1208_flowers_blue.jpg'
}
```

How will I do it ?If this question have already answered then please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest way would be to use a REGEX:

```
echo preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '_', $str);
```

Comment: `echo str_replace ('.', '_', substr ($str, 0, strrpos ($str, '.'))) . strrchr ($str, '.');`

Comment: Yes, that works too. But sometimes, you may want to limit the use of so many functions in a single line. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove any non-word character(except a-zA-Z0-9_) then following regex will match non-word character

```
$str="1208.flowers.blue.jpg";
echo preg_replace("/\W(?=.*\.[^.]*$)/", "_", $str);
```

This will also remove the `.` from file name `1208.flowers.blue.jpg` to  `1208_flowers_blue.jpg`

If you want to remove only `.` from filename small alteration is replace `\W` from regex to `\.`

```
$str="1208.flowers.blue.jpg";
echo preg_replace("/\.(?=.*\.[^.]*$)/", "_", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer also as  BenseidSeid in comment.

```
echo str_replace ('.', '_', substr ($str, 0, strrpos ($str, '.'))) . strrchr ($str, '.');
```

This solution fully based on string functions.